# substitute a value in a cell with its class, Excel

Tags: excel, dataframe, excel-formula

I got two Excel database. One, regarding only cities and their land, has two main columns:

```
database1
city land
 1    1
 2    1
 3    2
 4    2
```

The other database shows observations and the city where they happened.

```
database2
     -       city
observation1   4
observation2   3
observation3   1
observation4   1
```

I'd like to substitute each cities with the corresponding land, to get something like that:

```
     -       city   land
observation1   4      2
observation2   3      2
observation3   1      1
observation4   1      1
```

How do you think I can achieve that?

**solved with xlookup (or *cerca.x* in italian), I'll show you how:**

```
landdatabase2 =XLOOKUP(citydatabase2;citydatabase1;landdatabase1)
```

wonderful! thanks everyone

Comment: [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`.